# Trying to post a request using python to a .php site

Tags: php, python, python-requests

So I'd like to access the website http://marketinout.com/home/login.php but I'm running into some issues.

Here's what I've attempted.

```
import requests

payload = {'1': 'myemail', 'd': 'mypassword'}
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post("http://marketinout.com/home/login.php", data=payload)
r = s.get('http://marketinout.com/wl/my_watch_lists.php')

print(r.text)
```

The '1' and 'd' are the names of the username and password fields. 
I can clearly see form the html returned that it's not working. 
I also tried doing it in two stages where I enter the email get the new page then enter the password.

NOW WORKING: It's corrected now thanks to the first comment by @schwobaseggl
             I hadn't passed in the login_ok and do fields.
`payload = {'l': 'myemail', 'd': 'password', 'login_ok': '1', 'do': 'Sign In'}` worked great.

Comment: Hmm.. from a quick check of the link you provide, the post payload seems to look more like this: `payload = {'l': 'myemail', 'login_ok': '1', 'do': 'Sign In'}`

Comment: There is simply no password field on the website. Just go to it via browser and you will see.

Comment: There actually is. Once you put in the correct email a password field pops up. I'll try your edit. Thanks!

Comment: @schwobaseggl I attempted your addition of the login_ok and do fields with my password field and it didn't work.

Comment: Ah , I see. Well, then check the POST-request that your browser sends when you log in with your browser dev-tools to see what fields you actually need.

Comment: Ah! @schwobaseggl it now works thanks to your other fields I hadn't checked.